# Why is Celery periodic task not working? (Django)

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

It returns no errors, however when running `celery -A mysite beat -l info` & `celery -A mysite worker -l info` the task doesn't happen. When trying the same structure in another Django project it works fine.
Help please!

My code:

*mysite/settings.py* (Only CELERY part)

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Nairobi'
```

*mysite/**init**.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

*mysite/celery.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
app = Celery('mysite')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

*personal/tasks.py*

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')),
    name="task_deleteFiles",
    ignore_result=True
)
def task_deleteFiles():
    logger.info("Files Deleted")
```

PS: If necessary I can post the outputs from Celery

Comment: You have to set up a heartbeat - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957134/celery-heartbeat-not-working?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354064/django-celerybeat-periodic-task-only-runs-once

Comment: @dmitryro I also thought so, however the task works completely fine in another project (simply by changing the names from the files).

Comment: A heartbeat is environment-specific (Docker, Vagrant, VM) and is **a process** that may not be running consistently in your current environment - you need to verify if this process is running for this specific environment and adjust the configuration accordingly.

Comment: @dmitryro I completely understand that (even done some further research in the topic), the settings.py part is identical to another website of mine  and it works fine (even without the heartbeat), somehow the other website works and this one doesn't.

Comment: Also the heartbeat is provided by the command: celery -A mysite beat -l info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently by deleting app.py and app.pyc (which were under the personal file) celery works perfectly normal. Python was possibly trying to import somehow the module, strangely it didn't return any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

For others who find this page: If you are using Docker and you have changed celery beat settings during development, then there's a reasonable chance the container has old `.pyc` files that it is using as cache.

To avoid this error, delete all *.pyc files from your repo and add `**/*.pyc` to `.dockerignore`.